# PHP file_get_contents('php://input') very slow

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-get-contents

I have a complex PHP application that uses an ESB model built with Zend Framework v1.x. Performance has become an issue, and now I know why: reading the php://input stream is consistently taking almost exactly 10 seconds.

Here is a snippet from an XDebug trace log:

```
0.3985    6935880    -> Zend_Controller_Request_Http->getRawBody() /var/www/vas/Adapters/Database/application/controllers/AdapterController.php:473
0.3985    6936104    -> file_get_contents() /usr/share/php/ZendFramework-1.12.0/library/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php:961
10.4134   6936096    -> trim() /usr/share/php/ZendFramework-1.12.0/library/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php:963
```

We deploy a ESB model, with requests going fro the portal, to the ESB, to the data base adapter. Hitting any one server by itself doesn't seem to be problematic, but as soon as the request goes between servers (which are actually vhosts on the same server), the problem rears  itself.

Comment: Can you monitor network traffic on the requesting server and side if it's on the read or request side?

Comment: It is on the read side. The delay specifically occurs at the first request to read php://input, regardless of when that occurs in the application.

Comment: So further `php://input` requests don't perform this way? Is it possible to test with another type of request?

Comment: Php://input can, generally, only be read once during a Web request. Subsequent attempts just return false.

Comment: Right, I didn't read that comment right initially.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but I am doing some research of PHP based ESB. Are building your own ESB model or are you using something from Zend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in either Apache httpd or PHP, as well as a bug in Zend Framework v 1.x.

The bug occurs when a content-length header's value exceeds the actual content length.

For example,

```
curl http://localhost/index.php -H "Content-Length: 3" --data "12"
```

In the above example, a 10 second timeout must be reached after calling file_get_contents('php://input') before the request body is returned.

In Zend Framework v1.x, setting the raw body of a Zend_HTTP_Client object causes a Content-Length header to be calculated and injected into the request. However, unless the request is a POST, PUT or DELETE request, the content will be omitted from the actual request, which, in turn, triggers the Apache/PHP invalid-content-length bug.

I have opened a bug with PHP and will also open a bug with Zend Framework.